# Firestore get all subcollections of root collection with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, nosql

Hello i am new to angular and noSql databases i have a collection of "users"  each user have a collection named "products" .
What i want to do is to retreive all the products of all the users so i have to get the list of all products i have in my firestore database and display every product with the user who added it .
I tried like this :

```
getAllProducts(){
return this.firestore.collection("users")
.doc().collection("products") ; 
}
```

but i dont' know how to loop for the users to get the collection of products of each one neither how to assign every user to its product .

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy method called `collectionGroup` query that will retrieve data from different sub-collections all at once.

In your case, it would be like this:

```
this.firestore.collectionGroup('products').get();
```

This query does require you to create a index, so it won't work on your first try. When you run it for the first time, open the console. There, you will find a link to create a index in firestore. Once the index is done building(usually takes about 5 minutes), you will successfully get your products sub-collections.

You can read more about collection group query here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query